# Twitch Streamers freecodecamp project - DISPLAY ISSUE

Tags: javascript

My code doesn't display logo, display name and status on the webpage although they showed up in the console. Please help me pinpoint the problem. I greatly appreciate it! Thank you!

Here's my pen:
https://codepen.io/cmtran/pen/vJGRWJ?editors=1111`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var user_arr = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
  var channelURL = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/channels/';
  var streamURL ='https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/';
 var status;
  var display_name;
  var logoURL;

  for (var i = 0; i < user_arr.length; i++) {
    (function(i) { // protects i in an immediately called function
      $.getJSON(streamURL + user_arr[i] + '?callback=?', function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        if(data.stream === null){
          $.getJSON(channelURL + user_arr[i] + '?callback=?',function(data){
            var display_name = data.display_name;
            var logoURL = data.logo;
            status = "Offline";
          })
        }
        else{
          display_name = data.stream.channel.display_name;
         // console.log(display_name);
        logoURL = data.stream.channel.logo;
          status = "Online";
    }
  $("#user_info").prepend("<div class= 'row'>" + "<div class='col-md-4'>" + "<img src= '" + logoURL + "'>" + "</div>"
 + "<div class= 'col-md-4'>" + display_name + "</div>" + "<div class = 'col-md-4'>" + status + "</div></div>");    


      });
    })(i);
}







  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$("#user_info")` with `$(".user_info")` and it will work. In your codepen's HTML, .user_info is a class and not an id. =)

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you very much Astro Boogie! It's able to display now but I found another glitch , which is not all usernames are displayed and some of them repeat themselves, so I am confused as to where I made a mistake. I would appreciate it if you could point it out for me!